# tomcat server not running after uncommenting servlet tags in web.xml

Tags: tomcat, perl, cgi

I am running tomcatserver and i need to execute a perl script. I searched online and found out that i need to uncomment in conf/web.xml

```
<servlet>
       <servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
         <param-name>debug</param-name>
         <param-value>6</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
         <param-name>cgiPathPrefix</param-name>
         <param-value>WEB-INF/cgi</param-value>
       </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
```

i did that and did a server restart. Now I am not able to connect to the server. I went through a lot of how to online and finally found this [tomcat cgi](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/how-do-I-enable-CGI-scripts-in-Tomcat-6-td2091698.html). I am not able to reach the server. It shows a blank page. In a time crunch.

Comment: What do the error logs say?

Answer (score 1):

In the file `/usr/local/tomcat/conf/context.xml`

look for

```
<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
<Context>
```

and change it to

```
<Context privileged="true">
```

then restart tomcat.